# Read settings / sections from the web.config or app.config file

Tags: .net, asp.net, configurationsection

I have many Connection strings in my web.config file. I also have a "dataConfiguration" setting in the same file which specifies what database my app connects to.

How do I read the "defaultDatabase" setting / section from the

Please see below xml file. Many thanks in advance

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="blablabla"
   <add name="mySQlServerDb"
  </connectionStrings>

  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="blablabla/>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have done it in the past:

```
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration;

DatabaseSettings dbSettings = (DatabaseSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataConfiguration");
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbSettings.DefaultDatabase].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: +1 - I was about to break out some code using ConfigurationManager.GetSection, and hadn't spotted that this is actually a config block from the enterprise library.